How do I use a custom font in an SVG embedded in a webpage?
My web page uses a font (Omnes Pro) which is not included with most operating systems. This is obviously not a problem for the most part because I can just load it in the css file from an OTF file with:
@font-face {
    font-family: "Omnes Pro Bold";
    src: url("fonts/Omnes_Pro_Bold.otf") format("opentype");
}

However, I'm not sure how to get this custom font to be used by the SVG file.
As it stands, when I display the image including text which uses the font using an img tag with HTML, it just shows the text as some default font instead of the expected font set within the SVG.
I expected that this would just pull from the CSS loading the font, but I'd guess that the SVG isn't referencing the right place to get the font from the CSS, I'm not entirely sure what's going on though, so that's why I'm here!
As an additional note on the same topic, I need to be able to edit the contents of some of these text elements using JavaScript, pointers towards how to achieve that would be helpful, if not I'll spend some proper time researching and possibly post a seperate question.
I have seen this post but I'm not sure how it applies to my problem because I am not using the svg tag, I just have a file which I created in Inkscape, I haven't created this SVG with code. If it helps, this is an example text element from the file:
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:22.5778px;line-height:0.9;font-family:'Omnes Pro';-inkscape-font-specification:'Omnes Pro';direction:rtl;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.545999;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:3.4;stroke-dasharray:1.05833, 0.264583"
       x="71.448624"
       y="103.02882"
       id="text16-2-2"
       inkscape:label="Second"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:9.87778px;font-family:'Omnes Pro';-inkscape-font-specification:'Omnes Pro, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;text-align:end;direction:ltr;text-anchor:end;stroke-width:0.546"
         x="73.127846"
         y="103.02882"
         id="tspan17-4-3">Second </tspan></text>

I've also seen recommendations to convert the text elements to paths, but that doesn't work in my case because I need to be able to edit the text later using code, which could make things very complicated as I'd need my code to be able to create text elements with the right font anyways, then convert them to paths using JS since it has to be dynamic.
Effectively, my goal is an image with dynamic text elements, if there's a better way of doing that than SVGs please let me know, this is just the best way I could think of doing it with my skill set.

This question is similar to: Why is my SVG file not using my font file?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@herrstrietzel Edit made. I'd seen it but I couldn't really make sense of it in application to my own problem so I had assumed it was a different thing, apologies for that.

If your ultimate goal is an interactive SVG with JS applied the <img> tag wont't work as images need to be selfcontained (with fonts embedded as base64 encoded data URLs). You can inline your SVG directly in HTML, load a font and manipulate it with JS. Otherwise you could create a web component or use an object tag with inlined JS.

@herrstrietzel Ah ok, so I've inlined the SVG, I can see that in the text elements there's a style property which has font-family as an attribute, it still refers only to a font on my system though, changing it to a font specified in the CSS doesn't work (goes to default). Could you elaborate on how I get it to use that custom font a little please?

In your svg you're applying a "omni pro" but you font-face rule specified a "omni pro bold". Better use the bare family name and specify multiple font-face rules for each weight and style. Also check the relative paths. If you succeeded to apply the font to HTML elements it should work for SVG as well

Embed the font directly into the svg.
For example:
<svg width="200" height="100">
  <defs>
    <font id="OmnesProBold">
      <font-face
        font-family="OmnesProBold"
        units-per-em="1000"
        panose-1="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
      >
        <font-face-src>
          <font-face-uri src="fonts/Omnes_Pro_Bold.otf"/>
        </font-face-src>
      </font-face>
    </font>
  </defs>
  <text x="10" y="50" font-family="OmnesProBold" font-size="20">This text uses Omnes Pro Bold</text>
</svg>


This doesn't work in any modern browser. Please see the compatibility stats

Aw it would have been really useful if it did.
